# Term for "the fatty" used by teenagers

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, offensive-language

"In seventh grade, I was diagnosed with scoliosis. My nightmare began. A brace restricted my movement and my life; I could not bend or turn, let alone continue with my favorite hobby—dancing. I was dubbed ___ for the baggy clothes that covered my shameful brace." (Self-made sentence in an essay)

I am looking for an insulting term to fill in the blank that means the fatty which is used by teenagers. I can only think of "the fatty". Either one phrase or one word will do.

Comment: It doesn't say that the clothes made the speaker look fat, only that the clothes were baggy. You could look for a term that relates to that bagginess. Unless there is a specific reason you have not disclosed, it wouldn't have to be an existing term, teenager insults aren't always found in dictionaries.

Comment: Do you have any particular teenagers in mind? Teenage slang often varies between cities and regions, as well as between ethnic groups and social classes and settings (slang in a school may be very different to that in a church group or sports club or institution for young offenders). I suggest you go and do research: if not by listening to the specific kids you're interested in, then on social media or in sources like Urban Dictionary.

Comment: Steve McQueen used "The blob".

Comment: What’s the setting? Demographics? Year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not quite sure how much teens use these kind of insults nowdays, but [macmillanthesaurus](https://www.macmillanthesaurus.com/topics/insulting-words-for-fat-people) lists some which I think would fit in your sentence, ex. lump, fatso, porker.

From the link, here are the definitions of some of the insults one in such case could use:

- lump: noun; someone, especially a child, who is heavy
- porker: noun, informal; an insulting word for someone who is fat
- fatso: noun, informal; an insulting word for someone who is fat